# How search in java enum?

Tags: java, enums, constants, enumeration

I have set of constants like:

```
public static final String CONST1="abc";
public static final String CONST2="cde";
public static final String CONST3="ftr";
...................................
public static final String CONSTN="zya";
```

In an application, I need to check if some value is in some set of constants, like:

```
if (String val in [CONST1,CONST2,CONST3]) {
do something;}
else {
....
```

Is it possible to do this with enum? Or is it better use a set or an array?
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you need is [Enum.valueOf()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String%29)

> Returns the enum constant of the specified enum type with the
>   specified name. The name must match exactly an identifier used to
>   declare an enum constant in this type. (Extraneous whitespace
>   characters are not permitted.)

Here is an example of what I usually do when working with Enums and might have "bad" data coming in.

```
public class EnumTest
{
    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        final Option o = Option.safeValueOf(args[0]);
        switch(o)
        {
            case CHOICE_A: // fall through
            case CHOICE_B: // fall through
            case CHOICE_C: // fall through
                System.out.format("You selected %s", o );
                break;
            case CHOICE_D:
                System.out.format("You selected %s", o);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.format("Default Choice is %s", o );
        }
    }

    public enum Option
    {
        UNRECOGNIZED_CHOICE, CHOICE_A, CHOICE_B, CHOICE_C;

        // this hides the Exception handling code
        // so you don't litter your code with try/catch blocks
        Option safeValueOf(final String s)
        {
            try
            {
                return Option.valueOf(s);
            }
            catch (final IllegalArgumentException e)
            {
                return UNRECOGNIZED_CHOICE;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

you can also convert the `Array` of values from `Option.values()` into an [`EnumSet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) and search them and avoid the overhead of the possible `Exception` if you think it will be getting lots of bad data.

Comment: A fine response. Covers all aspects and nicely written.

Answer (score 4):

You can use enums in switch statement as @Dims suggested:

```
switch (val) {
    case CONST1: case CONST2: case CONST3:
        do_something();
    break;
    case CONST4:
        do_something_else();
    break;
    default:
        // we should not be here?!?
    break;
}
```

where I assume that `val` is an Enum. You can create it as @jarrod-roberson suggested:

```
    val = MyEnum.valueOf(stringValue);
```

Comment: Be sure to wrap that `valueOf()` in a try-catch if there is a chance that `stringValue` won't be one of the enum values. Also be aware that if that case happens a lot you will be spending a non-trivial amount of time constructing the Exception object(s) and going through the try-catch mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

Check out java.util.EnumSet - it is a special Set implementation optimized for enums.